# Is it possible that $\forall y \in X \quad \|y-b\| < \max(\|y-a\|, \|y+a\|) $?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space. Let $a, b \in X$ be noncollinear vectors. Is it possible that 
\begin{equation}
  \forall y \in X \quad \|y-b\| < \max(\|y-a\|, \|y+a\|)?
\end{equation}

So far, I wasn't able to find a norm which would satisfy that and I know that this isn't true in normed spaces with norm generated by inner product - exemplary vector $y \in X$ for which the statement is false can be found on line given by the equation $y = b + \beta x$, where $\langle\beta, a\rangle = 0$ and $\beta \ne 0$.

Comment: In your counterexample, if we look at the point $(x,y) = (0,b)$, then $\|y-b\| = 0 < \|y-a\|$ trivially. In fact, if we look at $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean norm, then we can show for any $b$ sufficiently close to the origin, the property holds true when $a = (0,1)$ (just show it for $b=(0,0)$ and apply continuity of the norm).

Comment: @forgottenarrow Are you sure this example works? It appears to me that the property is not true in any inner product space  (as OP already observed).

Comment: Let $b=(0,0)$ and $a=(1,0)$. Let's focus on the square of the Euclidean metric $d^2$. Then for any $y = (y_1,y_2)$,

$$d^2(y,b) = y_1^2+y_2^2.$$

$$\max(d^2(y,a),d^2(y,-a)) = y_1^2 + 2|y_1| + 1 + y_2^2 \geq d^2(y,b)+1.$$

Comment: But we want $b$ to be noncollinear with $a$, that is, that there is no $x$ such that $b=xa$.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake there. My thought was to apply continuity of the norms. However, if the square distance is very large, then after taking a square root, the difference in norms becomes negligible, and any small perturbation will violate the inequality. You were right.

Comment: Did you want the property to hold for all non-collinear $a,b \in X$, or just for there to exist $a,b \in X$ such that the property holds?

Comment: @Kakuro I don’t understand what you mean by the equation $y = b+\beta x$. $\beta$ is a vector. What is $x$ here? A  variable real? And then at which point of the line is the inequation violated?

Comment: @forgottenarrow I want for that property to hold for at least one pair of non-collinear $a, b \in X$. It definitely can't hold for all possible $a,b \in X$ as the property is false for example for (a, b) such that $\| a\| ≤ \| b \|$ and $y=0$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $x$ would be a well-chosen real number. Then $\max \|y\pm a\|^2 = \|y\|^2 + \|a\|^2 + 2|\langle y,a\rangle|= \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 + 2x\langle b,\beta\rangle + x^2\|\beta\|^2 + 2|\langle a,b\rangle|$. But then,

$$\max \|y\pm a\|^2 = \max \|a \pm b\|^2 + 2x\langle b,\beta\rangle + x^2\|\beta\|^2$$

$$\|y-b\|^2 = x^2\|\beta\|^2$$.

So as $x\text{sgn}(\langle b,\beta\rangle)$ grows toward $-\infty$, $\max \|y\pm a\|^2 - \|y-b\|^2$ goes to negative infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, but with $||(x_1,x_2)||=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$?

Consider $a=(2,2)$ and $b=(-1,1)$. Then $||y-b||=\max(|y_1+1|,|y_2-1|)$.

Clearly $|y_1+1|<\max(|y_1-2|,|y_1+2|)$ and $|y_2-1|<\max(|y_2-2|,|y_2+2|)$.

Since $\max(||y-a||,||y+a||)=\max(|y_1-2|,|y_2-2|,|y_1+2|,|y_2+2|)$ we conclude the desired result.

The "cheat" here is that on both coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $a$ and $b$ are collinear.